# Compare sets interval (0,1) and the points of inside of circle with radius 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given interval (0,1) and the set of points inside the circle with radius = 1.
The task is to compare the sets.( by their size)
I got a feeling the set with points of circle is larger, because if interval point is x, then you have infinite points, where (x,y) is circles point as there are infinite y you can choose.
How to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Are you supposed to compare their geometric features? The colour of their hair? Their worth on the NYSE?

Comment: Compare them by their size

Comment: You should [edit] this information into your question. Clarify, add some context to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact both sets have the same size - that of $\mathbb{R}$, uncountable infinity. To make it simpler consider $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$, we need an isomorphism between those sets.

Define this isomorphism $\phi:[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ as follows:

Let $0.x_1 x_2 x_3 ...$ be the decimal expansion of $ x\in [0,1]$. This is then mapped to
$$\phi(0.x_1x_2x_3x_4 ...) = (0.x_1x_3x_5..., 0.x_2x_4x_6...)$$

Obviously this is injective (only way to get $0$ is to have $x_i=0$ for all $i$). It is surjective as well, as we have infinitely many of those expansions and for each given pair $(0.x_1x_2x_3..., 0.y_1y_2y_3...)\in [0,1]^2$ we can construct the preimage: $0.x_1y_1x_2y_2...$

It's crazy to know that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ and even $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality and are in fact isomorphic, but that's how infinity works - it's full of surprises.

I hope you got the idea and creating a bijection from $[0,1]^2$ to the unit circle should be just a small step from here.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer

Comment: I hope that's what you were looking for. You could also compare them regarding area - Then the unit circle would have $\pi$ while the line have area $0$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.